# How to close the PDO connection in php singleton class

Tags: php, pdo, singleton

I have a singleton class for PDO, below is the relevant part of the class

```
    public static function getInstance( $config )
            {
                if ( ! isset(self::$instance))
                    self::$instance = new self( $config );

                return self::$instance;
            }

            public  function __construct( $config )
            {
                self::$start        =   self::timer();

                try
                {
                    $host       =   $config['host'];
                    $dbname     =   $config['name'];
                    $user       =   $config['user'];
                    $password   =   $config['password'];

                    self::$objInstance  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",
                                                    "$user",
                                                    "$password",
                                                    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
                                                );

                    self::$objInstance -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
                }
                catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                    //need to log for security
                    die('PDO CONNECTION ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
                }

            }

public static function closeConnection ( )
        {
            try
            {
                self::$objInstance      =   null;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                //OPTIMIZE**************************** to do
                //file_put_contents("log/dberror.log", "Date: " . date('M j Y - G:i:s') . " ---- Error: " . $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            self::$end  =   self::timer();

        }
```

So here everything works fine, but when I call the static `closeConnection()` after any DB operation, it makes the PDO instance null, which is fine but again calling the PDO instance gives error, beacuse PDO is now null due to calling closeconnection. My question is how to deal with closing the PDO in singleton class ?

Comment: in singleton constructor must be private

Comment: @HalayemAnis yes right ... but I have some other issue. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
self::$objInstance      =   null;
```

into

```
self::$instance = null;
```

Because you trying remove PDO object instead of singleton object.

Comment: yup it seems the right way , but singleton concept will be useless here ?

Comment: @A-NirVaan , I do not know your architecture. But many people consists that singleton is anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php):

> Upon successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO
>   class is returned to your script. The connection remains active for
>   the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection, you need to
>   destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are
>   deleted--you do this by assigning `NULL` to the variable that holds the
>   object. **If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close
>   the connection when your script ends.**

With a singleton, the entire life of the connection should be controlled from the singleton itself. As such, I would rely on the documented automatic closing of connections and not expose a method to close the connection at all (for the same reasons the constructor should not be exposed).

Comment: Thanks , if we rely on auto close of pdo connection, wont be the resource will be held back unlike explicitly closing ?

Comment: @A-NirVaan It will, but isn't that the whole point of a singleton? No calling code is exposed to the resource management.